# ngOptions and select, required attribute satisfied when target property is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm really not sure how to explain this, but I'm going to do my best, I have a plunker too, so that hopefully helps.

http://plnkr.co/edit/mbKvRoXl92f4zPJLxRGJ?p=preview

**TLDR VERSION:**

1. Select 'abcdefg@yahoo.com' from the dropdown menu, to satisfy its required attribute.
2. Delete 'abcdefg@yahoo.com' from the "Home Email" input field.
3. Notice that the dropdown menu no longer has an email selected, yet its required attribute is still satisfied.

**LONG WINDED VERSION**

What I have is some input fields, that are tied to objects in an array ($scope.contact.emails). The array containing those objects is then tied to a select element. The select element has an ng-model directive, containing the object from the array that is currently selected.

When the page loads, nothing is selected, so the ng-model (default_email) tied to the select is undefined, and the "Required" text is shown next to the select element.

Now it is important to notice, that the "Email" field is required, but the "Home Email" field is not required. If I select in the dropdown that my "Preferred Email" is the email in the "Home Email" field (abcdefg@yahoo.com), the select requirement is met, and the default_email property in my contact object is assigned the object represented by that field (default_email":{"id":"home_email","name":"Home Email","address":"abcdefg@yahoo.com"})

Here is the problem, if I now delete the contents of the "Home Email" input box so that it is empty, the select changes to "Please Select Preferred Email", but the object is still assigned to the default_email property in the contact object, only now it is missing the property "address", since it no longer meets the requirement of type="email" specified on the input. The real problem is that I need the "Required" label to be displayed, but is not. This is due to default_email being defined, only the object that is assigned to it, is missing the property I actually need, i.e. "address".

Any help is greatly appreciated, please let me know if more details or clarification will help, really new to angular, so please be patient.

Comment: try to short your post, most will not read all question

Answer (score 0):

You have form into form therefore external form `contactForm` doesn't see internal: `ng-form="innerForm"`.

I don't know if its good design.

**But some work around:**

add to controller:

```
 $scope.isRequired = function(){
  return $scope.isRequiredBool;
 };

 $scope.isEmpty = function(value){
   if(value == ''){
     $scope.isRequiredBool = true;
  } 
};
```

After, add `|| isRequired()` to `ng-show`

```
<span ng-show="contactForm.default_email.$error.required || isRequired()" class="help-block">Required</span>
```

After, add `ng-change="isEmpty(email.address)"` to `innerForm` input.

It should work:

<kbd>[Your modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a0csSasM2jU6YDCKXULr?p=preview)</kbd>

Hope it helped you,

Comment: First thanks for your help. Few things though, I should have been clearer, I don't just need for the Required span to still appear but for the form to be invalid still and the submit button at bottom to be disabled (form needs to be invalid/valid). Second, the solution you posted doesn't exactly work, since while the Required label remains, it does not go away after selecting the other email from the box. Finally, the nested forms is due to the dynamic names given to the elements within them. I've found that angular does not like dynamic names for form validation. Updated plunker too.

Comment: well, I didn't think to solve all issues and after run unitest, I wanted to show you concept that with to forms you have no choice but use `$scope` as bridge.  In my case I used `isRequired` method. Further, I never saw 1 form into another, with encapsulation problems. If you will define 1 form, sure, it will be easy to fix. Good luck

Comment: BTW add `ng-change` to combobox to remove flag back